# How to output one plot each time with two or more actionbuttons in RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

I create a RMarkdown file and it works well.Even though I think it's not so friendly comparing to  shiny when creating a database website.

Now I met a problem that I want to add two or more plots in RMarkdown(one input box and two or more actionbuttons) but only one actionbutton works(so only one related plot output normally).

I don't know if I should adjust my code chunk or ignored something important.

Here is my part code:

````
---
title: "123"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
##    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
```
abc {.sidebar data-width=373} 
=========================================================

```{r}
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

inputPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol", 
        "Select Gene Symbol:", 
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 360,
        selected = "Sele"
      )
)

actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "plot1")
actionButton(inputId = "plot2", label = "plot2")

```


Home {.tabset}
===================================

```{r ,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,echo=FALSE,out.height=8}
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
    ggplot(data =mean_data, aes(x = Name, y =.data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")
  })
renderPlot({
p1()
})
```


```{r ,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,echo=FALSE,out.height=10}
p2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2,{
    req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
                        req(input$selectGeneSymbol)
    ggplot(data =mean_data, aes(x = Name, y =.data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")
})
renderPlot({
p2()
})
```
````

Just as the code chunk showned above, only the `p1` works well and it happened nothing when I click the `p2` related actionbutton.

Could somebody give me some advice.

I also put the `p1` and `p2` togather but I get nothing.
I think that I must miss something.

Vary appreciate for any help.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. a short, complete Rmarkdown document that shows this error, thanks!

Comment: @starja thanks, I have improved my question.

Comment: I guess you can only show one plot per layout area, see the [example layouts](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html). You would need to put the plots into different columns/rows/tabsets

Comment: @starja Sorry, I tried what you suggested but my plot is not so suitbale for per layout area. 
I just want to refresh my  plot output each time in the same area because there are two different code chunks.
Somebody suggested that if I should add the if else into my code chunk.  But I think there must be a best solution in RMarkdown.

Comment: Anbody here can help me  ?